# How can I get lava in a bucket without taking the source block?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am trying to make a moat out of lava, but I can't get the lava in the bucket. Do I have to take the source block?

Comment: @Robotnik Different game.

Answer (score 8):

You can't. You have to take the source block.

Unlike water, lava doesn't ever create new source blocks. The only way to get source lava is to take it from somewhere else, and the only way to get flow lava is naturally flowing from source lava since flow lava can't be picked up.

Comment: There are lava generator designs but I think they must be in the Nether.

Comment: @Timtech There are occasionally tutorials on how to generate lava, but since they always rely on bugs they quickly become non-functional with an update. I'm not aware of any bugs that currently exist that allow lava generation.

Comment: Okay, it must have been a plugin on the Nether Skyblock server.